# how to find the 5 consecutive 'census' for each machine in postgresql?(and the 5 'census' should not appear at the beginning or end)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hey the schema is like this: for the whole dataset, we should order by machine_id first, then order by ss2k. after that, for each machine, we should find all the rows with consecutively 5 flag = 'census'. In this dataset, the result should be in row 31 to row 35. Although row 20 to row 24 and row 48 to row 52 are also consecutively 5 flag = 'census', but because they are either at the beginning or the end after we sort the dataset by machine_id and ss2k, we don't want that.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm.  The following gets you the first such row:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where flag = 'census') over (partition by machine_id order by ss2k rows between current row and 4 following) as census_cnt5,
             row_number() over (partition by machine_id order by ss2k) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by machine_id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where census_cnt5 = 5 and
      seqnum <> 1 and
      seqnum <= cnt - 5;
```

Comment: Hey, yes,  "seqnum <> 1 and
      seqnum < cnt - 5" will help to filter out all the census blocks which appear at the beginning and ending of the data, but it also filter out some of the census blocks which appear in the middle..

Comment: @Cathy . . . "because they are either at the beginning or the end after we sort the dataset by machine_id and ss2k, we don't want that."

Comment: I will send you an example.

Comment: Would you please look at the second picture in the question part, the where part filter out the part in the red circle too, but I need to keep that part...

Comment: the part in the red circle does not meet 'seqnum <> 1 and
      seqnum < cnt - 5'...

Comment: @Cathy . . . I think the last condition needs to be `<=` rather than `<`.

Comment: I just checked that part on my postgresql server, we still have not caught the red circle part.. I think the seqnum is the sequence number, the row number. the cnt is like "select machien

Comment: @Cathy . . . Something is wrong with your `cnt` calculation.  It should be constant for all rows for the machine.  You probably put an `order by` in that calculation.

Comment: You are right, Gordon, I put order by which messed things up. Sorry about that.  But would you please look at the third picture? In this case, at the end of 12-01-2018, the block have 17'census' , not 5. and I cannot decide how many census in a block at all.

Comment: Similarly, at the beginning of the day, the census block might be longer than 5 too. and I will not know how long the block will be. But the rule here is, as long as the block appear in the beginning or in the ending of the day, we don't want the block. But if the block is in the middle, we will keep it. 'order by ss2k' is used to sort those records basing on time. The definition of a block is at least 5 census. but we don't know how long the blocks will really be for each machine. We need to update the ' where part'.. Thanks a lot

Comment: We should change   (seqnum <> 1 and
      seqnum < cnt - 5) . because if at the beginning, 6 census appear together, we will keep the 6th row, but actually we should not becasue the 6th row also belongs to the block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188301/discussion-between-cathy-and-gordon-linoff).

Comment: hi, @ Gordon Linoff, instead of only return where census_cnt5 = 5, is there a way to return all the rows in the blocks in yellow? Thanks.

Comment: @Cathy . . . I would suggest that you ask a new question.